Snap applications crash with HDMI connected on a Raspberry PI 5
I have recently installed Ubuntu 24.10 on Raspberry PI 5, 8GB. I used Raspberry's official image.
The system loads fine. Everything seems to work OK except the Snap applications. When I start any of the Snap applications, their UI crashes, like in the attached image. After a while the whole system freezes.
The only situation when they seem to work fine is when I connect to the Raspberry PI 5 via an RDP client.
As soon as I plug in an HDMI device (I tried two), it fails like in the attached picture.
Does anyone have any experience with this?


I’ve removed Snapd, then installed Chromium from a non-Ununtu repository. Now it works. Looks like Snapd is the problem.
